# Java Scanner Delimeter not working as I expected

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have got a question about a code I have written

```
package salescities;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalesCities {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double totalSales = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int missingCount = 0;
    String line;
    File file;
    Scanner input;
try {

        file = new File("sales.txt");
        input = new Scanner(file);
        input.useDelimiter(":");
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            input.next();
            line = input.nextLine();
            try{
                totalSales += Double.parseDouble(line);
                count++;
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                missingCount++;
            }

        }
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(totalSales + " " +missingCount);
}
```

}

And the file im trying to read is like this

```
New York: 23.5678
New Jersey: no reports
Rio de Janeiro: 12.3654
```

When i run the program however it prints out 0.0 3 like all is missing.
The problem is when i run the debugger to see whats happening to line so parseDouble isn't functioning and i saw that line is a string that has this

```
: 23.5678
```

and I don't understand why if I'm using ":" as delimeter. I expected only the number without the colon. Can someone answer me?

ps: this is an exercise from a book that's quite simple but the book uses a class TextIO that is implemented by them. just wanted to try scanner instead of their code.

Comment: Not really an answer, but just a hint: in this case, it might be easier to just use string.split(": ") on the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner#nextLine` grabs the rest of the line, regardless of the delimiter.

> **Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.** This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line. — [Scanner#nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Comment: so i have to use another next() function and then another nextLine to discard the \n character?

Comment: Should he use just .next() then?

Comment: My first thought was that you should just use `next` twice, but I was unsure if that would grab all of the input up to the next `:` (including line-seperators). Glad to know it worked for you.